# How to read ® character from Windows-1252 file and write to UTF-8 file

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

I have an input file in Windows-1252 encoding that contains the '®' character. I need to write this character to a UTF-8 file. Also assume I must use Python 2.7. Seems easy enough, but I keep getting UnicodeDecodeErrors.

I originally had just opened the original file using `codecs.open()` with UTF-8 encoding, which worked fine for all of the ASCII characters until it encountered the ® symbol, whereupon it choked with the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 2867043: 
invalid start byte
```

I knew that I would have to properly decode it as cp1252 to fix this problem, so I opened it in the proper encoding and then encoded the data as UTF-8 prior to writing. But that produced a new error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 22: 
ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is a minimum working example:

```
with codecs.open('in.txt', mode='rb', encoding='cp1252') as inf:
    with codecs.open('out.txt', mode='wb', encoding='utf-8') as of:
        for line in inf:
            of.write(line.encode('utf-8'))
```

Here is the contents of `in.txt`:

```
Sample file

Here is my sample file® yay.
```

I thought perhaps I could just open it in 'rb' mode with no encoding specified and specifically handle the decoding and encoding of each line like so:

```
of.write(line.decode('cp1252').encode('utf-8'))
```

But that also didn't work, giving the same error as when I just opened it as UTF-8.

How do I read data from a Windows-1252 file, properly decode it then encode it as UTF-8 and write it to a UTF-8 file? The above method has always worked for me in the past until I encountered the ® character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is not in Windows-1252 if 0xC2 should represent the `®` character; in Windows-1252, 0xC2 is `Â`.

However, you should just use

```
of.write(line)
```

since encoding properly is the whole reason you're using `codecs` in the first place.

Comment: That solved the problem, but can you help me understand a little better. Is codecs somehow handling the encoding for me? P.S. I will accept this but it won't let me for a few more minutes.

Comment: @BobDylan: yes, doing the en/decoding on the fly is the **job** of the codecs package. Read the docs!

Comment: Yes, I tried learning more, but the docs only appear to document all of the methods. There is not really a (low-level) description of how it works. If you have any links that explain it further beyond merely listing all the methods with a brief description of what they do but not how they work, I would love to learn more. No biggie if not, this is the accepted answer as is and I appreciate your time.

Comment: @BobDylan: really, just the docs: *`codecs.open(filename, mode[, encoding[, errors[, buffering]]])`   **Open an encoded file using the given mode and return a wrapped version providing transparent encoding/decoding.** .*

Comment: That tells me *what* it does, not *how* it does it. But even so, it works. I was just hoping to learn more. Thanks